# XML values in Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I've opened up my XML file in excel.

I'm interested in displaying the numerical values on a table, they are enclosed between the Item tags. An extract is below.

My problem is that, excel doesn't pick up any Value columns for "Item".
It did however pick up the value between "Derivation", which is also included in the "Item" tag.
What is happening? And how do I get retrieve my numerical values inside the each Item tag?

So just to clarify, excel is displaying "Item Code, "Data_Type", "Type" - but no values - ie 2,610,921. It also shows Derivation Value, "Derivation Error" and "Status"
That's what confuses me the most - Derivation Values between the Derivation tags gets picked up, but not the values between the Item tags.

```
  <item code="R11213" data_type="MONETARY" type="apra:oCPInsuranceRiskCharge.total">2,610,921</item> 

  <item code="R12977" data_type="MONETARY" type="apra:totalPremiumLiabilities.total.groupPLInsuranceRiskCharge">1,167,570</item> 

  <item code="R14437" data_type="MONETARY" type="apra:insuranceConcentrationRiskChargeLevel2">1,311,163</item> 

  <item code="CS23747" data_type="MONETARY" type="apra:adjustmentsToPrescribedCapitalAmountAsApprovedByAPRA.total">
  0 
 <derivation error="" status="SUCCESSFUL">
 <![CDATA[ SUM(CS23750)
  ]]> 
  </derivation>
  </item>
```

Thanks
Gemmo

Comment: Your XML element ITEM contains mixed content (character data and subelement DERIVATION). Excel cannot handle mixed content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I got the concept now.
I was developing to build an import file for a software. The item tags were accepted and there's no need for the extra tags, which were only meant for the software to do some checks etc.

So to answer the question, Axel was right. You cannot build list within list in excel.
And in my case I was able to just use the Item tags, flat structure. Which worked in my situation.